# VS linker fails with "object already exists" error for std::string methods

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, build, linker

First of all I must stress that I'm trying for quite some time to solve it, and I don't know what I am missing (or more precisely, what I don't understand). Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I have a project called *static_tools* that compiles to a static lib which is called **static_tools.lib** and it uses STL. I compile that project with /MD, and it compiles successfully.

Another project called *system* compiles to a DLL which is called **system.dll** also uses STL and links with static_tools.lib. I compile that project with /MD and it compiles successfully.

*Here is the problem:* Another (3rd) project called *systemclient* compiles to a DLL which is called **systemclient.dll** also uses STL and links with **system.dll** and **static_tools.lib**. I compile that project with /MD and the linker fails :-( .

The error is that methods of std::string already exists in system.dll. **I think** it happens because system.dll got the objects from static_tools.lib, but if it is true, it sounds like it is impossible to use static lib, which doesn't make sense.

UPDATE - some extra details requested:

- I am using VS2013, but it also happened in VS2010
- The error I am getting from the linker:

```
2>static_tools.lib(pipe_client.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >(wchar_t const *)" (??0?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(pipe_client.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(pipe_client.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > & __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t>>::operator+=(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (??Y?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@AEBV01@@Z) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(pipe_client.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > & __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t>>::append(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t>>const &)"(?append@?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@AEBV12@@Z) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(pipe_client.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > & __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t>>::assign(wchar_t const *,unsigned __int64)" (?assign@?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@PEB_W_K@Z) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(pipe_client.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: wchar_t const * __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t>>::c_str(void)const " (?c_str@?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEBAPEB_WXZ) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(pipe_client.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: bool
__cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t>>::empty(void)const " (?empty@?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEBA_NXZ) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(pipe_client.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: unsigned
__int64 __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t>>::size(void)const " (?size@?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEBA_KXZ) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(error_tracer.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >(void)" (??0?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(error_tracer.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)

2>static_tools.lib(error_tracer.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: wchar_t const * __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t>>::c_str(void)const " (?c_str@?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QEBAPEB_WXZ) already defined in system.lib(system.dll)
```

I have explicitly instantiate std::basic_string in stdafx.h, but it didn't work :-(.

Can anyone help me out here? Also a small explanation would be nice :-).

Comment: I'd just guess to name a DLL **system.dll** on a windows platform might not be a good idea!

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Gonmator - VS2013, but it also happened in VS2010

Comment: @Angew - I added the messages to the question - thanks! :-)

Comment: Can you try renaming the DLL, as per @πάνταῥεῖ's comment?

Comment: @Angew - changed the name, didn't do much :-(

Comment: Weird. You're not doing any explicit template instatiation/specialisation (such as to provide a `declspec`), are you?

Comment: @Angew - I am doing such thing in system.dll (my own string inherits from std::string). And the DLLs compile successfully without the static_tools.lib.

Comment: Well, if you're explicitly instantiating a template, that instantiation is a class (not a template), and thus it no longer behaves as a template. Which means it's subject to "multiple definition" linker errors normally. Perhaps the explicit instantiations are `#include`d in both the DLL and the static lib? That would put the instnatiated code in both, leading the to duplicity.

Comment: The instantiated code is only in the system.dll, not in the static lib. The systemclient.dll and the system.dll link fine if I remove the static lib.

Comment: Note that if the static lib happens to use the same specialisation of `std::basic_string` as the DLL (without being aware of the explicit instantiations), it will generate its own implicit instantiations, which will then conflict with the explicit ones in the DLL. Could this be happening?

Comment: @Angew - I'm using std::string and std::wstring in static_tools.lib. Could that be the problem????

Comment: @TCS That's exactly what I said in the previous comment - the static lib will have its own (implicit) instantiations, then the DLL will have its explicit instantiations and they will clash.

Comment: @Angew - I just realized thats what you wrote (took me time to actually understand it...). Anyway, how can I fix it? or in other words (if I got it right) can I let each DLL linking with the lib create its own instantiation? There must be a way to use std::string in static library...

Comment: @Angew - Also, if that is the problem then why does system.dll links successfully and only systemclient.dll has the problem with the object in system.dll? Sounds like there is an instansiation in system.dll which clashes with the instansiation in systemclient.dll. But again, how can I resolve it?!

Comment: @TCS The important bit to be aware of is that static libraries are not linked, only DLLs are. So the linker doesn't kick in until a DLL is linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments, your problem seems to be that you're explicitly instantiating `std::string` in the DLL and implicitly instantiating it in the staic library - these two instantiations will then cause a linker error.

The cleanest solution would be to not explicitly instantiate the template in the DLL. You mentioned you're doing it because your class is derived from `std::string`. It's generally a bad idea to (publically) derive from standard library containers, because they don't have a virtual destructor. So I'd look for ways to change your design accordingly, which would remove the need for explicit instantiation and the problem would disappear.

If that is not possible for one reason or another, you have a few other options. You mentioned VS2013, which should have support for the `extern template` feature of C++11. You could use that to provide an explicit instantiation declaration in the static library (so that it won't generate its own implicit instantiation) - it would then satisfy its link dependencies by the explicit instantiation in the DLL. Of course, that would mean all users of the static lib would have to supply the explicit instantation.

Another option would be to actually explicitly instantiate `std::string` in the static library; the DLL would then use that explicit instantiation as well.

**EDIT**

One more option I can think of: create a new DLL (e.g. `string.dll`) which will only contain the explicitly instantiated `std::string`. Use `extern template` in the other two DLLs and the static lib, and link `string.dll` to the other two DLLs.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing that I've tried actually work (according to the suggestions). I've tried to extern template the basic_string and I've tried to explicitly instantiate the basic string. In all scenarios I get that system.dll already defined the basic_string when I try to link the systemclient.dll. :-(

Comment: I'm really bummed :-(

Comment: The "edit" is what I've done (more or less :-)) and tried to avoid. Thanks for all your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same *linker* errors for ***std::basic_string*** methods.

The linker did not throw errors for all the methods but only for ***std::basic_string<wchar_t>*** specialization.

I tried all the solutions suggested by ***Angew is no longer proud of SO*** but the problem did not solve. I tried declaring the **explicit instantiation for *std::basic_string*** but the linker errors did not go away.

Then I declared **explicit instantiation** for the individual functions of ***std::basic_string*** for which the linker errors are thrown and the errors for those functions were resolved.

The *linker error messages* itself shows the *function definition* which then can be used for **explicit instantiation declaration.**

Some of the declarations I used are as follows:

```
//basic_string constructor, move constructor,destructor:
extern template  std::basic_string<wchar_t, struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>, class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::basic_string() noexcept;
extern template  std::basic_string<wchar_t, struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>, class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<wchar_t> &&) noexcept;
extern template  std::_String_alloc< std::_String_base_types<wchar_t, class std::allocator<wchar_t> >>::~_String_alloc(void);
extern template  std::basic_string<wchar_t, struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>, class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string();

// assign method.
extern template class std::basic_string<wchar_t, struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>, class std::allocator<wchar_t> > & __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t, struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>, class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::assign(wchar_t const *, unsigned __int64);
// size method
extern template unsigned __int64  __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t, struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>, class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::size(void) const noexcept;
// _Tidy
extern template  void __cdecl std::basic_string<wchar_t, struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>, class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_Tidy(bool, unsigned __int64);
// c_str
extern template  wchar_t const *  std::basic_string<wchar_t, struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>, class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::c_str(void)const noexcept;
```

EDIT:

The above declarations resolve the linker errors except for one error.
**The explicit instantiation declaration for std::_String_alloc destructor** does not resolve the linker error for the same destructor.

May be I declare it wrong. I am still looking for its solution. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296574/std-string-alloc-destructor-linker-error)