# Prevent implicit instantiation of std::string/std::wstring in static library

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdstring, wstring

I have written a sample static library.
I want to suppress the implicit instantiation of std::string/std::wstring. I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522320/vs-linker-fails-with-object-already-exists-error-for-stdstring-methods) and I declared the explicit instantiation of template class std::basic_string (extern template). I expected that the static lib wont contain any symbols for std::basic_string. But the dumpbin utility showed there are symbols present for basic_string in the library.
The code is as follows:

```
// testLib.h   
#pragma once

namespace staticLib{

    void TestLib();
}

// testLib.cpp  
#include < string >     
#include "testLib.h";

//Explicit instantiation declaration   
extern template class std::basic_string< char> ; // Is this correct?

namespace staticLib {

    void TestLib() {
        std::string str = "Testing";
        str.size();
        str.erase();
    }
}
```

The dumpbin log :
[image]

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there any way to suppress the implicit instantiation of std::string/std::wstring.
2. There is an 'explicit instantiation declaration for std::basic_string' in testLib.cpp. Is that correct ?
3. Why the declaration of explicit instantiation of basic_string does not prevent the implicit instantiation and the symbols in the library.

Comment: *"I want to suppress the implicit instantiation of std::string/std::wstring"* Why?

Comment: I would expect that the explicit instantiation declaration happens to late, and `string<char>` is already implicitly instantiated by this point...

Comment: @dyp. Thanks for your comments. I am trying to link a static lib with a DLL(Say DLL A). This DLL again links with another DLL (Say DLL abc ). The DLL abc explicitly instantiates the std::basic_string<wchar_t> and inherits it. During linking I get linker errors for some methods of std::basic_string<wchar_t> for static lib and DLL abc. This happens because, both of them have symbols for std::basic_string<wchar_t>.

Comment: Hence, I want to suppress the symbols from static lib. I can not modify the abc.dll

Comment: The issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522320/vs-linker-fails-with-object-already-exists-error-for-stdstring-methods) question. Thank you @dyp